# iOS Storing and Loading Multiple web views in and from an array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

My app used to use a single UIWebView from the storyboard to display a users online data.

Now I have added the ability to have multiple accounts stored in the app, and so I would like to be able to have a separate UIWebView for each account, and show the appropriate one.

My app is a tabbed application, with one tab holding the account details in a table view, and the other with the UIWebView. This is what I have tried so far to have multiple web views.

In the table view controller, my didSelectRowAtIndexPath looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Generate the url (please note I've taken this code out)
    ...

    //Get the view controller that will hold the web view
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
    ViewerFirstViewController *viewerViewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    //Look for the web view in an array of web views
    [viewerViewController getWebView:indexPath.row];
    [viewerViewController setViewerUrl:viewerURL];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //Move to the tab that will hold the web view (bonus question - how can I animate this move?
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}
```

Now, for the view controller that will hold the web view

```
-(void)getWebView:(int)index
{
    if ([webViews objectAtIndex:index] == NULL) {
        [self createWebView:index];
        [self setDidExist:false];
        [self setWebView:[webViews objectAtIndex:index]];
    } else {
        [self setDidExist:true];
        [self setWebView:[webViews objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
}


-(void)createWebView(int)index
{
    float width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    float height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, width, height)];
    wv.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    wv.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    wv.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:wv];

    [webViews insertObject:wv atIndex:index];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:viewerUrl];
    if (didExist) {
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        [webView setHidden:false];
    } else {
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
}
```

It appears that the web view is being created as I am presented with a white screen that I can scroll in, but no page is being loaded. I'm assuming this won't work to hide the web views not currently in use either.

The web view should only load the page if it didn't exist previously. If it did already exist then it should present the loaded web view that is stored in the array.

Am I loading the URL at the wrong time or something? I'm unsure as to why I get a web view created but it's not filled with anything..

What seems to be happening is the web view isn't being added to the array when I create it - the array is empty and so webView isn't being set and so the url is never loaded into it However the code I use to add it to the array seems ok to me..

```
[webViews insertObject:wv atIndex:index];
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37933/discussion-between-chris-byatt-and-a-live)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it from storing them in an NSMutableArray to an NSMutable Dictionary. This solved my problems.